# Subscription isUnsubscribed returns false even after onComplete called

Tags: rx-java, subscription, observable

I am trying to convert a callback in a reactive way, to do so, I use the following code

```
Observable.create(
    subscriber -> ref.authWithPassword(email, password, new FirebaseAuthResultHandler() {
      @Override public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
        subscriber.onNext(authData);
        subscriber.onCompleted();
      }

      @Override public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        subscriber.onError(firebaseError.toException());
      }
    }));
```

This is a one time callback so as soon as I get the result I want that any subscription finish.

So if I subscribe to this Observer and after onComplete is call, I call isUnsubscribe() I should get true, but I don´t.

```
Subscription subscribe = userProvider.login("some@gmail.com", "12345678")
        .subscribe();
    while (!subscribe.isUnsubscribed()) {
      Thread.sleep(100);
    }
```

On the code above we are never going out of the loop. Unless there was an error an onError was called.

Am I doing something wrong or is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Is it possible that `onAuthenticated` is never called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to set it up correctly using another thread and then check the state of the subscription and it returns isUnsubscribed (true)

So the problem has to be that I was calling it from the same thread. Even that I was getting the logs on the callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct (that the subscription should get unsubscribed after the onComplete) but (from what I see) your code will run on the same thread.

So `Thread.sleep` might not allow to run other operations. Instead of using sleep how about you attach a `.doOnUnsubscribe()` before the `subscribe` to check when it unsubscribes?

Comment: Obviously this code is ugly, was just a fast way to verify that. I would never use a Thread.sleep like that. I put logs in every callback and I can see all of them, included the onComplete callback from the subscription. 

I will try to use sth different than the sleep and see if still same result